# Why is there a vein on my left bicep but not one on my right bicep?

Tags: weight-loss, biceps, arms

I have a blue vein running down my left bicep but not on my right one. I have been told before that a vein on your bicep means you are losing fat, but should they be on both biceps or just one? Is this normal?

Comment: I actually have the same thing, but never really thought much about it. Looking forward to any answers.

Comment: Could be stretch mark for all I know. If it is, then it will recover over time and it is not a big deal.

Comment: I have the same problem only for me my right bicep has the vein and my left doesn’t. For me it’s weird because my left bicep peek is a little bigger then my right and not my arms have the same amount of body fat so I don’t know, I’m still a kid I’m 13 so it’s probably because my body is still developing but i won’t let that stop me from getting a left bicep vein.

Answer (score 7):

It's most likely perfectly normal. Bodies are not perfectly symmetrical, and while you may have the same vein in your right arm, it doesn't necessarily mean that it runs in the same place.